# Error Adding image in signup form yii2 advanced

Tags: image, file-upload, upload, yii2, image-upload

i want to add profile avatar in frontend/web/site/signup but there is an error
it said

> Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
>   Calling unknown method: frontend\models\SignupForm::save()

this is the signup.php on frontend/views/site/signup.php

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model \frontend\models\SignupForm */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$this->title = 'Signup';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-signup">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to signup:</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup'],['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['placeholder' => "First Name"]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Last Name"]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Username"]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['placeholder' => "Email"]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput(['placeholder' => "Password"]) ?>

                <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
                </div>

            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the SiteController.php

```
<?php namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii; use yii\base\InvalidParamException; use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException; use yii\web\Controller; use yii\web\UploadedFile; use yii\filters\VerbFilter; use yii\filters\AccessControl; use common\models\LoginForm; use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm; use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm; use frontend\models\SignupForm; use frontend\models\ContactForm;

/**  * Site controller  */ class SiteController extends Controller {
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout', 'signup'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['signup'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['?'],
                    ],
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function actions()
    {
        return [
            'error' => [
                'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
            ],
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Displays homepage.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            return $this->goBack();
        } else {
            return $this->render('login', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs out the current user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->goHome();
    }

    /**
     * Displays contact page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionContact()
    {
        $model = new ContactForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Thank you for contacting us. We will respond to you as soon as possible.');
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'There was an error sending your message.');
            }

            return $this->refresh();
        } else {
            return $this->render('contact', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays about page.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionAbout()
    {
        return $this->render('about');
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            //upload file
            $path = Yii::getAlias('@frontend') .'/web/upload/';
            $imageName = $model->username;
            $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
            $model->file->saveAs( 'uploads/img/user'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );
            $model->file->saveAs( $path.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension );
            //save in database
            $model->avatar = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;
            $model->save();

            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        }else{
          return $this->render('signup', [
              'model' => $model,
          ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Requests password reset.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionRequestPasswordReset()
    {
        $model = new PasswordResetRequestForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
            if ($model->sendEmail()) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Check your email for further instructions.');

                return $this->goHome();
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Sorry, we are unable to reset password for the provided email address.');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('requestPasswordResetToken', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Resets password.
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return mixed
     * @throws BadRequestHttpException
     */
    public function actionResetPassword($token)
    {
        try {
            $model = new ResetPasswordForm($token);
        } catch (InvalidParamException $e) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException($e->getMessage());
        }

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate() && $model->resetPassword()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'New password saved.');

            return $this->goHome();
        }

        return $this->render('resetPassword', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    } }


<?php
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;

/**
 * Site controller
 */
```

class SiteController extends Controller

and this is the SignupForm.php on frontend/models/SignupForm.php

```
<?php
namespace frontend\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use common\models\User;

/**
 * Signup form
 */
class SignupForm extends Model
{
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $username;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $avatar;
    public $file;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['first_name', 'required'],

            ['last_name', 'required'],

            [['file'],'file', 'extensions'=>'jpg, gif, png'],

            ['username', 'trim'],
            ['username', 'required'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

            ['email', 'trim'],
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

            ['password', 'required'],
            ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return User|null the saved model or null if saving fails
     */
    public function signup()
    {
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return null;
        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->first_name = $this->first_name;
        $user->first_name = $this->first_name;
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->avatar = $this->file;

        return $user->save() ? $user : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller `SiteController`, in action `actionSignup()` youre using:

```
$model->save()
```

Your model doesn't extends `ActiveRecord` class, so it don't have method `save()`.

Remove this `$model->save()` from controller, youre saving user anyway in method `signup()`.

Comment: Still error, 

now it said 

PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException

finfo_file(E:\Xampp\tmp\php4DF3.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Why?

Comment: Because youre calling method `saveAs()` two times. Remove one use, or add second parameter in first call to not delete temporary file `->saveAs($filePath, false);`